# Display specific data from CSV using PHP

Tags: php, csv

The code I have below is working but would like to narrow down my results. Basically at the moment it shows all the data from column 1 (date), 2 (name), and 3 (result).

Now, what I would like to do is search the CSV for the word 'Won' in column 3 and limit the search to 3 results. For example, it would show the latest 3 games that have got the word 'Won' in column 3.

```
$file_handle = fopen("future.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

print $line_of_text[1] . $line_of_text[2]. $line_of_text[3] . "<br />";

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: what do you mean latest? first three results found?

Comment: @Ghost yes... first 3 results found.

Comment: check out dave's answer, should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter of how many times "Won" shows up, and when it's 3/more then stop looping.

```
$file_handle = fopen("future.csv", "r");
$counter = 1;

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    if (strpos($line_of_text[3], 'Won') !== false) {
        print $line_of_text[1] . $line_of_text[2]. $line_of_text[3] . "<br />";
        if ($counter++ >= 3)
            break;
    }

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Worked perfectly. It was showing 4 results so just changed the counter from 3 > 2. Cheers.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally started the counter at 0. I'm glad it helped you! :)